# The box with information appears only by the picture being found at the top on the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The box with information appears only by the picture being found at the top on the left. 
When I move the cursor on the picture being found at the top on the left or in the centre, 
this box is coming up with information for me only by the picture being found at the top on the left.

It looks like a black box after moving the cursor in the centre picture:

http://imageshack.com/a/img924/6673/dwYNyU.jpg

My code:

```
<div id="content">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="site2.php" class="images">
                <img src="photo.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 5px" />
            </a>
            <div class="box">
                <p class="data-tooltip1" style="color: yellow">Tekst nr 1</p>
                <p class="data-tooltip2" style="color: red">Tekst nr 2</p>
                <p class="data-tooltip3" style="color: red">Tekst nr 3</p>
                <p class="data-tooltip4" style="color: red">Tekst nr 4</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="site2.php" class="images">
                <img src="photo.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 250px" />
            </a>
            <div class="box">
                <p class="data-tooltip1" style="color: yellow">Tekst nr 5</p>
                <p class="data-tooltip2" style="color: red">Tekst nr 6</p>
                <p class="data-tooltip3" style="color: red">Tekst nr 7</p>
                <p class="data-tooltip4" style="color: red">Tekst nr 8</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


CSS:
#content
{
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li
{
    display: block;
}

ul li:hover>.box
{
    display: block;
}

.images
{
    outline: none;
}

.images img
{
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 143px;
}

.images img:hover, .images img:focus
{
    border: 2px solid #FF0000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box
{
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 119px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 14px;
    left: 109px;
}

.data-tooltip1
{
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.data-tooltip2
{
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.data-tooltip3
{
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.data-tooltip4
{
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

The black box appears by the picture being found at the top on the left, and should jump out by the centre picture.
What I need to improve in my code, so that after moving the cursor in the centre picture for me a black box appears by this centre picture?

Comment: you need to add ids to target the one you want with #thisone

Answer (score 0):

> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the
>   nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the
>   viewport, like fixed).
>
> However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned
>   ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page
>   scrolling.

(source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

If I understand correctly, you want to show the black box next to the right image, if you hover that image. To do that, you need to place the black box relative to the image. The most simple method is to find the nearest common parent of the image and blackbox (in your case it can be `<li>`), take the style from from `<img src="photo.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 250px" />` and apply to the whole `<li>`:

`<li style="position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 250px" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mako. It works great! You are the champion.